# How can I add an xmlns to the <html> tag in tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht

According to Amazon's Kindle Publishing Guidelines, I need to add `xmlns:mbp="http://www.kreutzfeldt.de/mmc/mbp"` to the `<html>` tag in my html file.

I have tried many variants of the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \input{tex4ht.sty}
  \Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
    \Configure{PROLOG}{HTML+,HTML,@HTML}
%    \Configure{HTML+}{\HCode{plus-html test}}
%    \Configure{@HTML}{\HCode{at-html test}}
%    \Configure{HTML}{\HCode{naked-html test}}
    \Configure{*XML-STYLESHEET}{\HCode{xmlss test}}
    \Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{head test} }
    \HCode{<meta name="parameter" content="content">}
    \Configure{TITLE+}{This is my title}
  \EndPreamble

Content
\end{document}
```

Most of these succeed in inserting something in the `<head>` section, but nothing goes into the `<html>` tag.  `\Configure{PROLOG}` doesn't seem to make much if any difference.  When I don't comment out the `\Configure{HTML}` line, I get an error:

```
! Argument of \Configure has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.16 \end{document}
```

Obviously, I can insert this by hand, but it seems as though tex4ht is set up to do this.  `<rant>` of all the poorly-documented features of tex4ht, the stuff having to do with `\Configure{PROLOG}` seems to be the worst I've run into so far.`</rant>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\Configure{HTML}` has two parameters, you have only one in your example, so this may be source of the error. Note that there is `\Configure{@HTML}` for inserting code into `<html ...>`. `xml:lang` with correct language code is inserted by default, so you will need to provide it by yourself. And lastly, you don't need to use `\Configure{PROLOG}`.

Simple `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{@HTML}{xml:lang="en" xmlns:mbp="http://www.kreutzfeldt.de/mmc/mbp" \Hnewline}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

results in:

```
<html xml:lang="cs" xml:lang="en" xmlns:mbp="http://www.kreutzfeldt.de/mmc/mbp"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
>
```

Comment: AHA! That is what those numbers were in the documentation... the number of additional arguments! Also see my comment to @Martin.

Comment: @NatKuhn yes, these numbers are number of arguments :)

Answer (score 1):

The `\Configure` statements should be placed before `\begin{document}` in order to make `tex4ht` process them correctly, e.g. something like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{tex4ht.sty}
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{HTML}
  {\HCode{<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mbp="http://www.kreutzfeldt.de/mmc/mbp">}}
  {\HCode{</html>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta name="parameter" content="content">}}
\Configure{TITLE+}{This is my title}

\begin{document}
  \EndPreamble
  Content
\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reason, every time I had tried to put these `\Configure` commands before the `\begin{document`, I had gotten "Undefined control sequence" errors... here, it seems to work.  Anyway, thanks!